# SQL quick on selecting, very slow on updating

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

The select statement inside of this update query just takes around 4 seconds. But the update part takes a huge amount of time. The update here involves only 100.000 rows, while the table is around 1 milion rows.

Any idea what can be wrong or improved? (trying to create an index on id takes also so long.. it would help, in any case?)

the server is quite powerful I think, 512GB of RAM). The problem also is that the session gets disconnected because of how long it takes to do the update

```
update ghs_all_test set adm2_code=q.adm2 from
(select ghs.id,gaul.adm2_code AS adm2 from gaul_level_2_africa_sub gaul 
join ghs_all_test ghs on 
ghs.id<1500532 and gaul.the_bbox~ghs.geom  and
   ST_Within(ghs.geom,gaul.geom) 
  group by ghs.id,gaul.adm2_code) 
as q where q.id=ghs_all_test.id;
```

Comment: 1. What's the type of `adm2_code` column
2. How many unique results does the subselect returns?

Comment: How are you measuring that the SELECT is 4 seconds (is this in a GUI that shows a few rows at a time or did you actually pull all the data back)? Are there indexes that include adm2_code (the indexes will get updated too)?

Comment: it seems it was just a matter of server performance... tested again today and was really fast. Thanks in any case